# Dynamicaly created element , keeping only 2 div per line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code Dynamically div are created ,i want to keep only 2 div in one line.
sometimes i get 6 or 7 . how can i make only 2 div's i one line ??

I need to make 2 div inline and then add new line then again 2 div inline and new line .

```
colorList += "<div>";
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    colorList += "<div id='" + value + "' class='Productcolours' style='background-color:" + value + "; display: inline-block;'>" + value + "</div>";
});
colorList += "</div>";
```

Comment: Please explain what the mean "how can i make only 2 div's in one line"

Comment: You mean that you will only have two inner divs with display `inline-block`, right?

Comment: you are using $.each() function so you will create that many divs as your array elements

Comment: try, set inner div css width:50% and float:left; and set main div width like 100% or 1000px etc

Comment: @palaѕн i want to make 2 div inline , and then new line  .

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in 3 ways

1. Reduce the parent element's width to the width of two .Productcolours elements
2. set width of .Productcolours to 50%
3. add `<br>` tag by checking index in $.each

   ```
   if((index+1)%2==0 && index > 0)
   {
      colorList += "<br>"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
colorList += "<div>";
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    colorList += "<div id='" + value + "' class='Productcolours' style='background-color:" + value + "; display: inline-block;'>" + value + "</div>";

if( (index+1) % 2 == 0 ){
    colorList += '<br />' 
}

});
colorList += "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `<br/>`, I would suggest to insert a '' which can clear the space for you.

It will also help if you wish to do more instead of single line breaks between the lines. Thus, it gives a **more controlled design**:

```
colorList += "<div>";
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
    colorList += "<div id='" + value + "' class='Productcolours' style='background-color:" + value + "; display: inline-block;'>" + value + "</div>";

    if( (index+1) %2 == 0) {
        colorList += "<div class='clearLine'></div>";
    }
});
colorList += "</div>";
```

and in CSS, you may add:

```
.clearLine {
    margin: 5px 0;
    /* or whatever you like to mark a clean space
        or additional decorations
    */
}
```